# BigQuery: Repeat the same calculated value in multiple rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to get several simple queries into one new table using Googe Big Query. In the final table is existing revenue data per day (that I can simply draw from another table). I then want to calculate the average revenue per day of the current month and continue this value until the end of the month. So the final table is updated every day and includes actual data and forecasted data.

So far, I came up with the following, which generates an **error message** in combination: `Scalar subquery produced more than one element`

```
  #This gives me the date, the revenue per day and the info that it's actual data

            SELECT
            date, sum(revenue), 'ACTUAL' as type from `project.dataset.table` where date >"2020-01-01" and date < current_date() group by date
            union distinct

 # This shall provide the remaining dates of the current month  
            SELECT 
        (select calendar_date  FROM `project.dataset.calendar_table` where calendar_date >= current_date() and calendar_date <=DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), MONTH), INTERVAL 1 DAY)),

#This shall provide the average revenue per day so far and write this value for each day of the remaining month
            (SELECT  avg(revenue_daily)  FROM 
            (select  sum(revenue) as revenue_daily from `project.dataset.table` WHERE date > "2020-01-01" and extract(month from date) = extract (month from current_date()) group by date) as average_daily_revenue where calendar >= current_date()), 
        'FORECAST'
```

How I wish the final data looks like:

```
+------------+------------+----------+
|    date    |  revenue   |   type   |
+------------+------------+----------+
| 01.04.2020 | 100 €      | ACTUAL   |
| …          | 5.000 €    | ACTUAL   |
| 23.04.2020 | 200 €      | ACTUAL   |
| 24.04.2020 |  230,43 €  | FORECAST |
| 25.04.2020 |  230,43 €  | FORECAST |
| 26.04.2020 |  230,43 €  | FORECAST |
| 27.04.2020 |  230,43 €  | FORECAST |
| 28.04.2020 |  230,43 €  | FORECAST |
| 29.04.2020 |  230,43 €  | FORECAST |
| 30.04.2020 |  230,43 €  | FORECAST |
+------------+------------+----------+
```

The forecast value is simply the sum of the actual revenue of the month divided by the number of days the month had so far.

Thanks for any hint on how to approach this.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  If you need for things to be "updated", why not just use a view?

Comment: Sure, I just added some desired outcome. I think a view would lead me to the same problem as I don't get the calculated values to be repeated every remaining day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured something out, which creates the data I need. I'll still work on updating this every day automatically. But this is what I got so far:

```
select 
date, 'actual' as type, sum(revenue) as revenue from `project.dataset.revenue` where date >="2020-01-01" and date < current_date() group by date
union distinct
select calendar_date, 'forecast',(SELECT  avg(revenue_daily)  FROM 
(select  sum(revenue) as revenue_daily from `project.dataset.revenue` WHERE extract(year from date) = extract (year from current_date()) and extract(month from date) = extract (month from current_date()) group by date order by date) as average_daily_revenue),  FROM `project.dataset.calendar` where calendar_date >= current_date() and calendar_date <=DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), MONTH), INTERVAL 1 DAY) order by date
```

Comment: if this worked for you, could you please mark it as solution for the sake of community? Thank you!